# error Object of type User is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, django, serialization

Hi Im trying to obtain a json response to pass into the template, the isssue come when I ask  the owner attribute such is coming from User model. I received everything ok except message.owner. I tried to make User serializable object, first, but yet it don't work.
Here my code
Chat Model

'''

```
class ChatView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    model = Chat
    template_name = 'chats/all_chats.html'

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'chats/all_chats.html')

    def post(self, request):
        chat = Chat(text=request.POST['message'], owner=request.user)
        chat.save()
        return redirect(reverse('all_chat'))

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


class ChatMessagesView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request):
        User = get_user_model()

        messages = Chat.objects.all().order_by('created_at')[10:]
       
        
        results = []
        for message in messages:

            result = [message.text, message.owner, naturaltime(message.created_at)]
            results.append(result)
```

'''

Comment: most likely the message.owner is an UUID/ID that cant be serialized to json  with just results return , look at serializers for modules at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/  or with DRF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, the `message.owner` is an instance of the `User` model. There are many ways to serialize it. When you are looking to build an API, `django-rest-framework` might come in handy which does a lot of work for you.

A simple way could be implementing a function that serializes the object as you wish, given a simple example to write custom serializers:

`app.user.serializers.user`

```
def serialize(user):
    return {
        'id': user.id,
        'username': user.username,
        'email': user.email
    }
```

you can add embedding of certain serializers, eg. when you have a message serializer

`app.chat.serializers.chat`

```
from app.user.serializers.user import serialize as serialize_user

def serialize(chat, embed=None):
    return {
        'id': chat.id,
        'message': chat.message,
        'created_at': naturaltime(message.created_at),
        'owner': serialize_user(user=chat.owner) if 'user' in embed else chat.owner.id
    }
```

```
from app.chat.serializers.chat import serialize as serialize_chat

def get(self, request):
    message = Chat.objects.all().order_by('created_at')[10:]
    
    results = []
    for message in messages:

        result = [serialize_chat(chat=message, embed=['user'])]
        results.append(result)

    # I've kept is as original as possible, but it could be simplified as:
    # return [serialize_chat(chat=message, embed=['user']) for message in messages]
```

Which should result in something like

```
[
    {
        'id': 123,
        'message': 'my message',
        'owner': {
            'id': 456,
            'username': 'someone',
            'email': 'some@one.com',
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

But once again, this is just an example of serializing objects, there are better methods but this might get you back on the road again.